# Selenium not showing actual html page

Tags: java, selenium, jsoup

So I am using selenium and jsoup together to get the HTML page of a dynamic website. So the problem I am facing is that the page source I am getting using selenium is still not updated by the website. So I am searching on Flipkart.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc  = new Scanner(System.in);
        String searchtext = sc.nextLine();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\test\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        try{
            driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=" + searchtext+ "&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=on&as=off");
            String content  = driver.getPageSource();
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);
            Elements link = doc.getElementsByClass("_3BTv9X");
            System.out.println(link);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error " + e);
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I am using the driver. So I want the image link of the product. The class I have used is of images class. So if for example I searched masks, this is what I am getting,

```
<div class="_3BTv9X" style="height:280px;width:200px">
 <img class="_1Nyybr _30XEf0" alt="Van Heusen VHMSBRGPH53287" src="https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/image/612/612/k9u8zgw0/mask-respirator/2/k/j/vhmsbrgph53287-van-heusen-original-imafrjnfytwdxfka.jpeg?q=70">
</div>
<div class="_3BTv9X" style="height:280px;width:200px">
 <img class="_1Nyybr" alt="NHR Surgical Face Mask, Anti Pollution, 3 Ply Face Mask with ISO 9001:2015 Certification (Pack of 30) SG-30 Surgical Mask" src="//img1a.flixcart.com/www/linchpin/fk-cp-zion/img/placeholder_9951d0.svg">
</div>
```

For the above product, I am getting the full link of the image and below that, it is the basic Flipkart sign.

**Note:** This is just a small part of the output. The output actually contains 50+ products. I just want to show that some links are working and some are not.

Please help me. What should I do now?